# Token for Apache Ignite Web-Console

Tags: token, ignite

I'm trying to use the `Grid Gain Web Console` to monitor my `Ignite` cluster. I was able to launch the `web-console`, however when I launched the `web-console agent` it requires tokens to be entered and I have no clue where the token resides. The console tells me to go to `localhost/profile`, but the website is blocked. Where can I get the tokens for the web console agent?

Answer (score 2):

If you have just started setting up your Ignite monitoring environment, then I would suggest switching to [GridGain Control Center](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/control-center/latest/overview) right away. That's a successor of GridGain Web Console. The latter should be deprecated in 2021.

If you prefer to carry on with Web Console then open your profile/account screen and there you'll find the token that needs to be copied to the [web agent's configuration file](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/web-console/latest/web-agent-configuration#web-agent-configuration).

Answer (score 1):

If you download Web Agent from running Web Console, it comes with auth token already embedded in downloadable. Search for the download link on the left pane.

Having said that, Web Console is officially unsupported now so you should probably avoid depending on it.